# VS Code -- Unexpected Output Format /ERROR\

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im new to stackoverflow and VS Code. When I tried to debug my code I got error message, and couldn't fix it.

I uploaded the error message

[image]

and;
here is `mylaunch.json`:

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information,visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
```

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Etkin dosyayı derle ve dosyada hata ayıkla",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "gdb için düzgün yazdırmayı etkinleştir",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

and `task.json`:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

my **main.cpp** file is simply printes "Hello"

I installed MinGW and its directory is : C:\MinGW<
I hope there is someone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem recently. It seems that the auto-generated `tasks.json` is not set correctly and the executable is created in the root directory. This can be fixed by changing the `type` from `"cppbuild"` to `"shell"`.

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```